# Dynamic alternative to RIA services?

Tags: silverlight, json, wcf-ria-services, lob

I'm building a silverlight line of business application in silverlight 4 using RIA services currently and i'm finding RIA services to be more and more of a pain everyday..

A lot of the database interaction in this application doesn't follow the usual CRUD pattern and some of the data just doesn't "fit" with the RIA services style of doing things..

Even more importantly it doesn't fit the way my brain thinks about web services!

(I think that abstraction often gets in the way of the business problem you're trying to solve)

It's got to a point where a scary chunk of the code base is workarounds for the object context  and spoofing ID's to create some kind of unique key etc..

I'd also like to swap out entity framework for rob conery's massive (he thinks the same way as me about abstraction, dynamic typing etc..)

Are there any alternatives which work using dynamic typing and JSON?

If not I may have to roll my own!

Comment: Have you employed the presentation model pattern for your LOB application? It's a pain in the beginning but i think it pays off in the long run (especially combined with code generator). I'm also using RIA Services, combinded with NHibernate, and so far the experience was a mixed bag, but no big problems as of yet. You could also have a look at overriding the default Code generation on client side for getting rid of some of the pain points. 
One big drawback of using presentation model is that client side linq won't work in all cases, but will for simpler ones. I used T4 to get around it

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at WCF Data Services?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx

Comment: I've been using it successfully, but there are pain points with this as well. Specifically, working with the context (it's a lot more manual than RIA services) and cancelling scenarios. It's very nice to write LINQ queries and have it translated into url queries. Plus it's ODATA!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.. I'll take a look :-) i'm basically looking at exposing a REST service possibly using ASP.NET MVC and passing JSON back and forth between client and server.. possibly passing metadata for shared client & server side validations, and deserializing the JSON as a collection of dynamic ExpandoObjects.. No object context, no which instance of the context is this entity attached to.. (the "enterprisey people" are probably shuddering in horror :P ..you can probably tell i'm a rails guy by night)

Answer (score 0):

You might also find that WCF Web APIs suits you better.
http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2010/11/01/wcf-web-apis-http-your-way/#0_undefined,0_

Comment: Any newer solution to create a WPF LOB app that consumes a WebApi OData?

Comment: @Shimmy I have only used BreezeJS with an HTML client so far but they do have support for .Net clients too. Maybe that will suit?

http://www.getbreezenow.com/breeze-sharp/about